# How can add custom parameters to Angular 5 DataTables

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am working on an Angular5 project with PHP as backend. I am stuck at this level. 
The following is my code:

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  order: [0, 'desc'],
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    that.http
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'http://localhost/api/webapi/',
        dataTablesParameters,{ headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'token'
        })}
      ).subscribe(resp => {
        that.records = resp.data;
        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
  },
  columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'name' }]
};
```

As I observed in this code I am sending the default parameters of data tables "dataTablesParameters". How can I add my custom parameter like (entryid) alongwith "dataTablesParameters"?

Please guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to just declare object like:

```
userData = { token: '', entryid : '' };
```

and at the time of calling ajax, you should merge both objects using Object.assign like:

```
Object.assign(dataTablesParameters,this.userData)

ajax: (dataTablesParameters:any, callback) => {
        that.http
          .post<DataTablesResponse>(
            'http://localhost/api/webapi/',Object.assign(dataTablesParameters,this.userData),{}).subscribe(resp => {
            that.records = resp.data;
            console.log(resp);
            callback({
              recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
              recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
              data: []
            });
          });
      },
```

Check this complete tutorial for you better understanding. [Angular 5 Datatables using JSON data with rerender](https://gethybridapp.com/angular-5-datatables-using-json-data-rerender/)

Comment: Superb Maaan... You did it...Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no way around creating a parent object as follows:

```
ParentObj = { dataTablesParameters: _dataTablesParameters , entryid:_entryid }
```

**Edit:** So your code will look like this

```
declare interface parentObj : { dataTablesParameters: any , entryid: any }

this.ParentObj = { dataTablesParameters: _dataTablesParameters , entryid:_entryid }

this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  order: [0, 'desc'],
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    that.http
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'http://localhost/api/webapi/',
        parentObj,{ headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'token'
        })}
      ).subscribe(resp => {
        that.records = resp.data;
        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
  },
  columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'name' }]
};
```

Send the parentObj instead of the dataTablesParameter you have inside your http request.

Comment: Could you please share a complete example?

Comment: Okay Thank you let me check.

Comment: Thank you. But still a little confused about _dataTablesParameters. How can I assign dataTablesParameters body to _dataTablesParameters?

Comment: @CodeLover Try doing this inside your component  initialization .  ngOnInit(): void { this.dataTablesParameters = //whatever you want it to be}